# Does expo-dev-client build auto reload?

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, mobile, expo

I'm trying to use expo-dev-client to develop my app. The app hasn't contained native dependency yet.
After following the set up in the Expo document, I lasted run the command '''eas build --platform ios --profile preview'''. It built an app. Then I installed the app on my IOS simulator. (I haven't registered my iPhone to ad hoc).
The app now has the newest source code. But after editing and saving new source code, the app installed on the simulator didn't update.
So, does expo-dev-client build auto-reload? Or how to update the newest code to the installed app on my IOS simulator?

Comment: The --profile preview is not using expo-dev-client, to use it you need to run eas with --profile development, you can read more about it here https://docs.expo.dev/build/eas-json/#development-builds

Answer (score 3):

No, you have to re-build it when you have a new release.
I recommend checcking https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/publishing/
You can see the changes when the code isn't builder with the simulator

Comment: Does it the same as the physical device?

Comment: Well, it depends, you can simulate a real mobile. Maybe some native configs won't exists, but mostly all the tests will work well on this simulator. Or, you can also install expo on your real mobile and test it in there with the QR code